# How to prevent a method from being accessed/ overwritten from outside a concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following model and concerns

```
def MyModel
   include ConcernA
   include ConcernB
end

module ConcernA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def print_a
    formatted_text
  end
protected
  def formatted_text
    "ConcernA"
  end
end

module ConcernB
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def print_b
    formatted_text
  end
protected
  def formatted_text
    "ConcernB"
  end
end
```

The `formatted_text` method gets overwritten

```
=> MyModel.print_a
= "ConcernB"

=> MyModel.print_b
= "ConcernB"
```

Is there a way to actually protect the `formatted_text` method so that it is only accessible within the concern and therefore not overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard protection. If someone wants to change something, they most likely will be able to. But you can devise some safeguards against accidental name clash.

For example, extract the method into its own namespace:

```
module ConcernA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def print_a
    Impl.new.formatted_text
  end

  class Impl
    def formatted_text
      "ConcernA"
    end
  end
end

module ConcernB
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def print_b
    Impl.new.formatted_text
  end

  class Impl
    def formatted_text
      "ConcernB"
    end
  end
end

class MyModel
   include ConcernA
   include ConcernB
end


MyModel.new.print_a # => "ConcernA"
MyModel.new.print_b # => "ConcernB"
```

This way, `ConcernA::Impl` and `ConcernB::Impl` are two unrelated classes and don't affect each other.

Comment: thanks @sergio this is exactly what I am looking for. I searched a lot before posting but did not come across this approach as a solution. I guess I was searching for the wrong thing. Out of interest, where should I have searched/ looked?

Comment: @AndyHarvey: yeah, I don't think you can google for this solution unless you can write one yourself (in which case, you don't need to google :) ). Just a few years of experience with ruby object model, I guess.